# How do i enable tabwidth of 2 in eclipse for erb?

Tags: eclipse, erb

How can i enable tabwidth and indent width of 2 in erb files in Eclipse ?

Comment: do you meant that when you hit tab it will add 2 spaces instead of default number of spaces? and same for indent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the [Aptana Studio 3/RadRails](http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails) plug-in (formerly Ruby Development Tools), then the setting should be under Window > Preferences > Aptana > Editors > Ruby:
[image: ruby editor]

If you're using the default Eclipse text editor, then you'll need to change the "Displayed tab width" setting under Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors:
[image: default editor]

I suppose it's  also possible that you've mapped the .erb file extension to a completely different editor in Eclipse, in which case you'll need to change the tab width for that editor.  Specific editor preferences supercede the general text editor preferences.